# Collections.sort and Object[]

Tags: java

so just writing a Abstract classes and interfaces program. my code so far:

```
package lesson8;

import java.util.Collections;

public class ShapeTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] shape = {new Square(4),
            new Rectangle(3, 2), 
            new RightTriangle(5,2), 
            new Square(2),
            new RightTriangle(2, 4),
            new Plus(3)};  
    Collections.sort(shape);
    }

}
```

my question is, why doesn't the Collection.sort() work with Object[]? how can i make it work? thanks!

Comment: How will it know how to compare them?

Comment: [Check the Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: Arrays.sort(Object[])?

Comment: sort by which property?

Comment: You could use the BeanComparator from apache commons beanutils?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Arrays.sort()` to sort arrays (in place). Moreover, there is no "natural" ordering for `Object`s, so you will have to pass a `Comparator<Object>` to the overloaded version of `Arrays.sort()` that takes a comparator, unless your `Object`s all implement `Comparable` and are all mutually comparable, as per [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Collections.sort()` expects a `Collection` as the argument, not an array. For arrays you have `Arrays.sort()`.

Second of all, in order for either `Collection.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()` to work for a `Collection` or array of `Object`s respectively, all these objects must be comparable to each other - they must implement the `Comparable` interface, and `e1.compareTo(e2)` must not throw a `ClassCastException` for each two elements of the `Collection` or array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the **[BeanComparator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html)** from apache commons beanutils, like this:

```
Collections.sort(personList, new BeanComparator("name"));
```

[Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/BeanComparatorSortingbasedonPropertiesofclass.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Collections.sort work by calling the `compareTo` method on the objects in the array, in order to determine the natural ordering of the objects. However, the class Object does not have a defined `compareTo` method, so the sort method has no way of knowing what the correct order is. As such it cannot sort the list.

If you want to sort the list using `Collections.sort`, then make sure all contained objects have a `compareTo` method defined.